# Apply php "dashesToCamelCase()" function to all css styled html text with in my various php files

Tags: php, text-formatting, capitalize

Here is my PHP function:

```
function dashesToCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) 
{

    //$str = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));
    $string = preg_replace( '/-(.?)/e',"strtoupper('$1')", strtolower( $string ) );

    if (!$capitalizeFirstCharacter) {
        $string[0] = strtolower($string[0]);
    }

    return $string;
}

echo dashesToCamelCase('e-F-I-L-Re-T-Fa');
```

Here is some of my HTML:

```
<header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">EFILRETFA</a></li>    
    </ul>
<div id = "linkone" >
<a href="http://www.efilretfa.org/">
<img src="image/maps/five.jpg"</a>
</div>


<?php
include 'includes/menu.php'; 
?>

<div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

And here is the CSS relating to this title:

```
a:link { 
color: grey;
background-color: white;
font-size: 15px;
border: 10px outset white;
font-family:2em Arial Black;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow : 5px silver;
}

a:visited { 
color: grey;
background-color: white;
font-size: 10px;
border: 10px outset white;
font-family:2em Arial Black;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow : 1px 2px 5px silver;
}

a:hover{
color: white;
background-color: grey;
font-size: 15px;
border: 10px inset white;
font-family:2em Arial Black;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: red;
letter-spacing: 3px;
word-spacing: 3px;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow : 1px 2px 5px silver;
}
```

I would like to apply the PHP function to the text for all the text that is wrapped in the "a" tag, but I'm unsure which way to do it best.

Thanks!
Mercedes

Comment: I have now embedded the php function 'dashesToCamel' into the html on my php page. It picks up the css but not the php function 'dashesToCamel' for the string given...please help :(

Comment: Hi, I have solved this by taking out "text-transform: uppercase;" from the css code. Hope this can help someone else!

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution to your problem. Would you consider adding your comment as the accepted answer so that future site visitors can find and benefit from your solution?